# случайное распределение значенией из списка в столбец датафрейма

Tags: pandas, dataframe, сравнение

Коллеги, добрый день!

Помогите решить задачу с подстановкой значений из списка в столбец. Имеются 2 датафрейма (старый и новый) и список:

spisok = ['Ivanov', 'Petrov', 'Sidorov']

df_old:

```
id     score    revie_date   in_charge
111      4      08.10.2019     Petrov
123      2      04.03.2019     Sidorov
145      5      04.04.2019     Ivanov
135      6      20.05.2019     Petrov
222      5      25.06.2019     Sidorov
```

df_new

```
id     score    revie_date   in_charge
367      6      18.07.2019     
123      2      04.03.2019     
257      5      04.06.2019     
945      6      01.05.2019     
222      5      25.06.2019
```

Задача, нужно в произвольном порядке назначить исполнителя из spisok, но сделать это так, чтобы задания были распределены более или менее поровну (т.е в датафрейме может быть более 1000 рядов).

Сравнить со старым списком и если там по id есть совпадения, то исполнителя взять/заменить из старого списка.

Чтобы результат был примерно таким:

df_new:

```
id     score    revie_date   in_charge
367      6      18.07.2019     Ivanov
123      2      04.03.2019     Sidorov
257      5      04.06.2019     Petrov
945      6      01.05.2019     Ivanov
222      5      25.06.2019     Sidorov
```

Я попытался сделать это через

```
df_new['in_charge'] = np.random.choice(spisok, size=len(df_new))
```

но результат совершенно не тот распределены не поровну и затем как сравнить с предыдущим df_old.

Comment: Вы хотите сделать равномерное распределение имён до или после корпирования? Т.е. если сделать это __до__ копирования то в результате врядли получится равномерное распределение...

Comment: Тут не принципиально на самом деле до или после...желательно в результате, чтобы не было сильного расхождение в кол-ве между людьми из списка

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функция [np.random.choice()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html) позволяет задать вероятности с которыми должны выбираться соответствующие элементы из списка.

Можно попробовать этим воспольховаться - для этого надо расчитать вероятности элементов из списка с учетом уже имеющихся элементов.

Пример:

```
names = ['a','b','c','d']

np.random.seed(321)

old = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': np.arange(10),
    'in_charge': np.random.choice(names, 10, p=[0.4, 0.25, 0.2, 0.15])
})

new = pd.DataFrame({'id': np.arange(100)})
```

сначала добавим в `new` значения для совпадающих `id`:

```
new['in_charge'] = new['id'].map(old.set_index('id')['in_charge'])
```

распределение значений:

```
In [75]: new['in_charge'].fillna('NaN').value_counts()
Out[75]:
NaN    90
d       4
a       3
b       2
c       1
Name: in_charge, dtype: int64
```

расчитываем новые вероятности:

```
tgt_probs = pd.Series([1 / len(names)] * len(names), index=names)
cur_probs = new['in_charge'].value_counts() / len(new)
new_probs = (tgt_probs - cur_probs).clip(lower=0) / (new['in_charge'].isna().sum() / len(new))
new_probs = new_probs.fillna(1 / len(names))
```

получилось:

```
In [76]: cur_probs
Out[76]:
a    0.04
c    0.02
d    0.02
b    0.02
Name: in_charge, dtype: float64

In [77]: new_probs
Out[77]:
a    0.233333
b    0.255556
c    0.255556
d    0.255556
dtype: float64
```

заполняем значения в соответствии с расчитанными вероятностями:

```
new.loc[new['in_charge'].isna(), 'in_charge'] = np.random.choice(names, new['in_charge'].isna().sum(), p=new_probs)
```

результат:

```
In [80]: new['in_charge'].value_counts()
Out[80]:
a    28
d    28
b    26
c    18
Name: in_charge, dtype: int64
```

PS идеально ровного распределения достичь не получится из-за природы `np.random.choice`

Comment: большое спасибо за детальный и полезный ответ!